# there is any port opening script or solution to increase security? I mean port is opened just when some port sequence detected on log

Tags: ssh, port-knocking

In order to increase security, for example on ssh remote connections, I:

1. open a non stardard port.
2. use mandatory digital certificates for authentication.
3. allow connection from a ip range only.

But I wonder if this is enough to protect my ssh remote access. I was wondering if there is any script or solution doing this:

- listen on syslog and filter ssh access intents.
- if a predefined ports sequence is detected, then open for some minutes your non standard ssh port, then close it again if there is no active session.

So this is a "ports key" implementation. Do you know if a similar solution exists? Do you think such a tool is interesting to increase security levels?

Comment: Looks like you are asking for [port-knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking). There are [many posts about this here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+port+knocking).

Comment: You will also want to look up "security by obscurity". Yes, it adds some level of security, but only by reducing the threat surface a little.

Comment: Denyhosts or fail2ban will fulfill your first requirement, and your second just describes basic VPN functionality (make certain network resources available for a limited time after authenticating over an unrelated set of ports).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article about port-knocking: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-port-knocking-to-hide-your-ssh-daemon-from-attackers-on-ubuntu

And as schroeder said above - this is security by obscurity, it does not make your system more secure. If you are looking for securing your box and still need access to it from any IP address, consider [using VPN with SSL certificates](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_vpn_with_Ubuntu_15.04.html) to authenticate against the system and then connect to your SSH server. Otherwise just allow access to your SSH from a range of trusted IPs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for port knocking, `knockd` used in conjunction with a good firewall like `iptables`.

Then use a script using `nmap` or `knock` to access the port.

Answer (score -1):

That's called port knocking.

A non standard port and port knoching doesn't make your machine more secure, namely if your password is strong, you don't need to use a non standard port. If your password isn't strong, using a non standard port won't help you. The same goes for a certificate.

Comment: I do not agree. By moving or even hiding a common port like ssh, you reduce your threat surface, and prevent 99% of the brute-force attempts you might otherwise experience. It's not an account compromise issue, but a load and logging issue.

Comment: @schroeder, go brute-force my server: that won't make it less secure.

Comment: you avoided my point